# How to split the large size .txt file data into small portion and insert into database?

Tags: java

Below is my code to read and split the text file content.

```
  try {

        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("F:\\Test.txt"));
        final char[] cbuf = new char[2048];
        final int length = br.read(cbuf);

        cbuf[length] = '@';
        String packet = new String(cbuf, 0, length + 1);
        final String[] splitedPacket=packet.split("@");
        for(int i=0;i<splitedPacket.length;i++)
        {
            if(splitedPacket[i].contains("POS"))
            {
                System.out.println(splitedPacket[i]+"@");
                preparedstatement=connection.prepareStatement("insert into inserttextfile([file]) values(?)");
                preparedstatement.setString(1, splitedPacket[i]+"@");
                preparedstatement.executeUpdate();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)br.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

It was working fine in my small size .txt file, but if I use more than 30 MB text file I get  array index out of bound exception.

So how to split and read this kind of .txt file and insert into database?
(particularly expecting for split the large size file(ex. like 5 MB from 30 MB) and insert into database)
Please guide me in this issue.

Comment: 1.you are not reading entire file read spece http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read() . Dont try to read all file content once. read in loop and insert into DB. Use Scanner to read based on delimiter.

Comment: Notepad file? You mean text file?

Comment: @m0skit0 yes .txt file.

Comment: Your off to a good start here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your doing it the hard way by not using readLine

```
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("F:\\Test.txt");
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));          
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while(line != null){

            //process your line here, it's just a String...   

            line = reader.readLine();
        }           

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ...
    } catch (IOException ex) {
```

Comment: ya its working well. Using this we can read upto how many size.

Comment: You can read a lot, probably 100 megabytes at least with your jvm settings. If you run out of memory look at how to increase the JVM memory size.

Answer (score 2):

```
 try (Scanner read = new Scanner(new File("/tmp/datafile.txt"));) {
        read.useDelimiter("@");
        while (read.hasNext()) {
            String splitedPacket = read.next();
            System.out.println(splitedPacket);
            // Perform DB Operation
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

1. Dont read the entire file.
2. Use Scanner to read and hold only one read @ any give time - to avoid OOM
3. If Possible Perform Db Operation as bulk .
          If you are running in one transaction, read 1000 records and process as separate bulk insert.

Comment: Not an Issue. I am glad that your issue resolved. Read the Spec always. it has lot of info.